# Dompdf library is not working in joomla

Tags: php, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, libxml2, dompdf

I am using Google's [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) library to download articles as pdf in my joomla site( test.guru99.com/arrays.html ), it was working fine before.

Now when i enabled [Rokbooster - loadtime optimizer](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokbooster) pdf downloader is stopped working. I have printed out the errors in a log file but i didn't understand what are the errors.

I have integrated dompdf library in joomla using [this](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_PDF_views). I know this issue is arise due to Rokbooster plugin.

Here's error log [file](http://www.filedropper.com/dompdferror), i just want to understand the error so that i can debug and solve the issue.

Comment: Only when running Rokbooster? I don't know enough about the extension to offer much help. But as a work around can you disable Rokbooster for certain URLs?

Comment: yes, i can disable it to exclude certain urls or certain files. Rokbooster compresses and combines the js and css files. you can check the example here http://test.guru99.com/what-is-php-first-php-program.html. Click 'pdf image' in right sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Use following link. It has properly described how to install the library step by step.
[Creating PDF views](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_PDF_views)